# How to update an app you created?

Tags: android, google-play

I made my first app, it's a simple to-do list app.

Link:
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.arjun.todolist

The problem is that the app I created is a very simple and basic app and I want to build on it to give extra features to it but I don't know how.
It would be helpful if you could point me in the right direction, any articles or guides will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- simply make changes to the project i.e add new features etc.
- go to build.gradle file and update version code and version name
- generate the signed apk with the same keystore that you used
  previously for this app.
- finaly go google play console and update the apk and you are done.

hope this will help you in someway.

Comment: And don't forget to upgrade the database version in case you are changing it's schema.